# If A is a subset of R with Lebesgue measure > 0 then are there a,b such that the measure of $[a,b]\cap A$ is b-a?

Tags: measure-theory

If $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure strictly greater than $0$, does it follow then that are there $a$ and $b$ such that the measure of $[a,b]\cap A$ is $b-a$?

Thank you.

Comment: If this fails, you need a measurable set that contains no intervals.

Comment: No. Hint: fat Cantor sets.

Comment: @Ben : I rettaged your question since this is not really a problem in set theory but rather in measure theory (though one may learn these topics as part of a classical analysis course).

Comment: @Ben: Please don't use the title as an integral part of the message; make the body of the message self-contained as a service to readers.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: Post as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, the answer is no; a counterexample is given by the [Smith-Volterra-Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), or fat Cantor set.

Answer (score 4):

What is actually true is this: for every set $C$ of positive measure and every $\epsilon < 1$ there is some open interval $(a,b)$ such that $\mu(C \cap (a,b)) \geq \epsilon |b-a|$.

I have always viewed this as an instance of one of [Littlewood's three principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%27s_three_principles_of_real_analysis) for analysis: a measurable set is almost an open set.

Comment: Any hint as to how one could see this?

Comment: It's called the Lebesgue density theorem and is often proved in textbooks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue's_density_theorem is a little cryptic because it covers the theorem for $\mathbb{R}^n$.